# Python: "__init__" won't load modules

Tags: python

following tutorials I have tried to create my own package without success. The path to the folder containing the package is in PYTHONPATH, the package folder has the "**init**.py" file and its modules.

```
mypath/my_packages/mymath
---------------------/__init__.py 
---------------------/add.py 
---------------------/division.py
---------------------/(other .py files)
```

The path/to/my_packages is in PYTHONPATH. I can see it in "sys.path" too.

I can "import mymath" if `__init__.py` is empty, but can't use any of its modules.
If I try to import modules from `__init__.py` (`from add import add` [the module add.py contains a function "add()"]), I get an error: 
"ImportError: No module named 'add'".

Comment: How about `from .add import add`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `path/to/my_packages` is in PYTHONPATH you should import packages like

```
from mymath.add import add
```

Or if you are in the mymath module (for example in `__init__`) you can also do relative imports, like

```
from .add import add
```

Comment: The first mode will also work from within the package's `__init__`. Both ways in `__init__`'s body will expose `mymath.add` to the module first importing `mymath`.